# Method Undefined

Tags: java, android

Edit: My original question is below the line. I decided to go with a much simpler approach to setting up a button and assigning a click function. I found it at the following link. He does a good job of explaining the difference between the 2 approaches...

[Android User Interface Design: Basic Buttons](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-interface-design_basic-buttons/)

---

I realize this is a popular question, but in all of the examples I've looked at the problem seems to be a simple detail that's been overlooked, and the detail is never the same. I'm sure this is basic. I'm just starting out with programming for Android and this is a modification of existing code.

The app has one button on a blank page, and I want the button click to send an int to my Arduino via the Amarino API. Here is my MainActivity code

```
package com.example.buttontest1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import at.abraxas.amarino.Amarino;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;


public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    private Button button;
    private static final String DEVICE_ADDRESS = "00:06:66:4B:E4:23";
    public Context foo1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
        Amarino.connect(this, DEVICE_ADDRESS);        
        setContentView(R.layout.main); 
        addListenerOnButton();        
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        //Select a specific button to bundle it with the action you want
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Amarino.sendDataToArduino(this, DEVICE_ADDRESS, 'j', 1);
            }

        });

    }

    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // stop Amarino's background service, we don't need it any more 
        Amarino.disconnect(this, DEVICE_ADDRESS);
    }
}
```

The error I see is this, referring to line 38:

> The method sendDataToArduino(Context, String, char, int) in the type
>   Amarino is not applicable for the arguments (new
>   View.OnClickListener(){}, String, char, int)

So there's a problem with the context and the method?

Comment: Think about where `this` is located. I think you are looking for `MainActivity.this`.

Answer (score 0):

Teh api expects the object of `Context` but you pass `this` to:

```
            Amarino.sendDataToArduino(this, DEVICE_ADDRESS, 'j', 1);
```

this is not an object of Context instead it is `OnClickListener` object.

Comment: `this` in this case would be a `View.OnClickListener` instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
Amarino.sendDataToArduino(this, DEVICE_ADDRESS, 'j', 1);
```

`this` here refers to`View.OnClickListener's` current instance. The compilation error basically says, `sendDataToArduino()` expects the first argument as `Context` but you are passing a `OnClickListener`

Answer (score 0):

`sendDataToArduino` expects its first argument to be of type `Context`. You are passing it a `View.onClickListener`. Instead of passing `this` as the first argument, try setting up a context as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002288/static-way-to-get-context-on-android) and pass that as the first argument.

Try adding the following in your onCreate method after the super call:

```
MainActivity.context = getApplicationContext();
```

Also add the following method after onCreate:

```
public static Context getAppContext() {
    return MainActivity.context;
}
```

Now call the method with:

```
Amarino.sendDataToArduino(getApppContext(), DEVICE_ADDRESS, 'j', 1);
```

Comment: I have tried replacing "this" with "this.getApplicationContext()", "getContext()", "Amarino.this", and "MainActivity.this". None have worked.

Comment: did you try setting up a context as mentioned in the link?

Comment: I'm having trouble following those instructions because I'm still new to this. It says to add "android:name="com.xyz.MyApplication">" to my Manifest file. Am I supposed to replace "xyz.MyApplication" with my information or should I type that verbatim?

Comment: I don't think you'll have to worry about the manifest part since you already have a working activity. I will update my answer to give more details.

Comment: Also, I don't know where to put the "public class MyApplication..." declaration. I get errors when I put it in the MainActivity.

Comment: Yeah don't use MyApplication. Your class is called MainActivity. See my updated answer.

Comment: Regarding the updated answer, the MainActivity.context line yields the error: "context cannot be resolved or is not a field". Same for the "return..." line.